# timeout: the monitored command dumped core

Tags: c++, arrays

i am running this code in online compiler showing dumped core error this program finding highest product of two pair.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void maximumproductpair(int arr[],int n){
sort(arr,arr+n);
reverse(arr,arr+n);
int prod;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
cout<<arr[i];
}
prod=prod*arr[0];
prod=*arr[1];
cout<<prod;
}

int main() 
{
int t,n;
int arr[n];
cin>>t;
cout<<"\n";
cin>>n;
cout<<"\n";
  while(t--){
  for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
  
     cin>>arr[i];
   }
 }
maximumproductpair(arr,n);
  return 0;
}
```

in code everything fine then why this error?

Comment: you are not initialing int t your while(t--) have not loop stop

Answer (score 0):

#### Mistake 1

The **problem** is that your `t` and `n` variables are uninitialized. This means both `t` and `n` have **garbage value**. And when you wrote:

```
int t,n;
int arr[n];//UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR because n has garbage value
```

You have **undefined behavior** because `n` has **garbage value**.

This is why it is advised that

> always initialize built in types in local/block scope.

#### Mistake 2

**Second**, note that in C++ the size of an array must be a **compile-time constant**. So take for example the following code snippets:

```
int n = 10;
int array[n]; //INCORRECT
```

The correct way to write the above would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int array[n]; //CORRECT
```

Similarly,

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int array[n]; //INCORRECT becasue n is not a constant expression
```

Also note that some compilers provide **compiler extension** that lets you have **variable length array**. You can read more about it at [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).

If you want to take the size of the array as input from the user then you should use **dynamic sized containers** like `std::vector` :

```
int n;
cin >>n;
std::vector<int> array(n);// CORRECT, this creates a vector of size n of elements of type int
```

Also see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Thanks but taking input from user does not show any error even without using const itself.

Comment: @igneousspark Yes you do not see any error because some compilers(like the one you're using) provide **compiler extension** that lets you write `int n; cin >> n; int arr[n];`. This is why you do not see error because the compiler you are using provides an extension that lets you do that. It's just that it is **not standard C++**. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)